Back EMF & Efficiency of a BLDC Motor
So I've recently designed and built a 3 phase, coreless, brushless DC synchronous motor. I'm trying to estimate its efficiency but struggling to figure out the equations. Specifically, how back EMF is treated when calculating the power in.
Let's say I am supplying an average of 10V, 1A per phase. Let's also say that at a given speed, the average back EMF is 1V.
So, would the power in to the motor be Phases * Voltage * Current? 3 * 10 * 1 = 30W?
Or would the power in to the motor be Phases * (Voltage - Back EMF) * Current? 3 * (10 - 1) * 1 = 27W?
Any clarification someone can provide would be appreciated.

Input power is Pi = 3 * VphaseRMS * IphaseRMS. Output power is Po = omega * T. BEMF is something internal that is of no concern for this calculation.

Don't forget power factor.

Ah, I was overcomplicating it then. Thank you very much!

@Andyaka what do you mean? He said it's BLDC
